# My Programatically set initial view is not loading

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I set an initial view controller from appdelegate through a login key

even my login key is true it's not loading my home tab view controller it's loading launch screen every time followed by login view controller. I checked my login view key changes through user default it's showing the value correctly.
 when I change any view controller from storyboard IB wise it's setting but my code is not working.
what's wrong with my code?

```
    if isLogin == false
           {
               self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
               let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
               let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
               self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
               self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
           }
           else
           {
               self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
               let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
               let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC")
               self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
               self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
           }
```

Comment: try using "instantiateInitialViewController()"  instead of "instantiateViewController()"

Comment: Not related to your question, but since the only thing changing in your flow is the controller identifier, you could just simplify your if/else to just return a different identifier (instead of duplicating identical code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in ios 13 or above you need to use `UIWindowSceneDelegate`. Use following method for initialise your app in `SceneDelegate` file,

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        if isLogin == false
        {
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        else
        {
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC")
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate File,

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

        } else {
            if isLogin == false
            {
                self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
            else
            {
                self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC")
                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

For below ios 13, no need to initialise window like `self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)`. Just use that application automatically creates window property in `AppDelegate`.

Comment: in app delegate right?, what if the device runs lower than ios 13 if i changed to this method

Comment: @Fido Please check updated answer

Comment: I checked with scene delegate not working. after launch screen it becomes black

Comment: Im testing this on simulator

Comment: @Fido I have added both file's code, please check.

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate

For example:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let vc = ViewController()
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Can you check that you don't set window after your function?

I think there are two possible reasons:

1. isLogin is always false
2. You set window twice ( may be after your function )

Comment: my login key is true. I printed. But still the same problem after changing to your code

Comment: @Fido can you share your project?